# Create JSON from datatable using JSON.NET

Tags: .net, json, json.net, automapper

I am getting a datatable from a database query from which i need to create a JSON.
If i do a direct serialization of the datatable using JSON.NET i get the following,

```
[{"Item_CODE":"A08","ITEM_NAME":"sampleName","ITEM_LOCATION":"Kolkata"}]
```

However i am looking for the following JSON format,

```
{
 "Codes": ["A08","A09","A10"],
 "ITEM_NAME": "sampleName",
 "ITEM_LOCATION": "Kolkata",
 }
```

I understand there is no direct way of doing this. So do i need to loop through the datatable and create the JSON on the fly ?
I was looking at the Automapper library and am interested in knowing if it could be done that way.
How do i map the JSON for automapper?

Comment: usually you'll want to have a data-structure mirroring the JSON, create this structure from the database and then just serialize it (`new { Codes =  ... }` with LINQ should do fine). In your example it looks as if you are basically there as soon as you collect the codes - if you want more help you should post the schema of your table as well - right now we have no way of knowing how to collect the codes - what is the key/group here?)

Comment: What Carsten says.  You can just return an anonymous type for the structure you are after.

Comment: So right now the db returns me a row for each item_code. I know how to create a data structure mirroring the JSON but not well versed with LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solution is using a custom converter and take control of the serialization -

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, settings);
// {"Codes":["A08","A09","A10"],"ITEM_NAME":"sampleName","ITEM_LOCATION":"Kolkata"}

internal class Product
{
    public List<string> Item_CODE { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_LOCATION { get; set; }
}

internal class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = value as DataTable;
        if (data != null)
        {
            var res = new Product
            {
                Item_CODE = new List<string>()
            };
            foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                res.Item_CODE.Add((string)row[0]);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res.ITEM_NAME)) res.ITEM_NAME = (string)row[1]; ;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res.ITEM_LOCATION)) res.ITEM_LOCATION = (string)row[2];
            }

            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("Codes");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            res.Item_CODE.ForEach(a => writer.WriteValue(a));
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WritePropertyName("ITEM_NAME");
            writer.WriteValue(res.ITEM_NAME);
            writer.WritePropertyName("ITEM_LOCATION");
            writer.WriteValue(res.ITEM_LOCATION);
            writer.WriteEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thansk for the snippet. What is the order class ?

Comment: I am confused.  I see this in the code var res = new Order
            {
                Item_CODE = new List<string>()
            };                        What is the Order class ?  I am new to .NET . Please help me understand.

Comment: I'm just initializing an instance of `Order` class and one of it's property which is a `List<string>`.

Comment: Also where is the Product class being used ?

Comment: oh, got this one. that's typo. use `Product` instead.

Comment: Awesome \m/   Thanks you.